# I have created the django but it is not loading my home page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am learning the Django app, and I am stuck. I don't know the error because the compiler is working fine, but the URL is not loading. Here is my code.

**views.py**

```
'''
from django.shortcuts import render
   def home(request):
       # prams={'name':'Abhinav', 'place':'Earth'}
       return render(request, "index.html") 
'''
```

**index.html**

```
'''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template Home</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to template:
<h1>Text Analyzer : Enter your text below : </h1>
<form action='/analyze' method='get'>
  <textarea name='text'  style='margin: 0px; width: 1498px; height:  166px;'></textarea><br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='removepunc'>Remove Punctuations<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='spaceremove'>Remove Space<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='capfirst'>Capitalize First<br>
  <input type='checkbox' name='newlineremove'>Remove New Line <br>
  <button type="submit">Analyzer</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

'''
```

**Urls.py**

```
'''
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('analyze/', views.analyze, name='analyze'),]
'''
```

There is no error, but the URL is not connecting; it should show the index.html file, but it shows the install app successfully, the Django app's default page. Please Help. I have mentioned the code above.

Comment: where is your analyze and home views.py located? in an app? please show your file structure.

Comment: I have mention my file structure in below answer block. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
textUtils
|
+templates
|    |
|    +analyze.html
|    +index.html
+text_Utils
|    |
|    +__pycache__
|    +__init__.py
|    +asgi.py
|    +settings.py
|    +urls.py
|    +views.py
|    +wsgi.py
+db.sqlite3
+manage.py
```

Here the views.home is accessing the index.html page

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following in your settings.py under `TEMPLATES = [.`

Replace

```
'DIRS': [],
```

with

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # in django2
or

'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates')],# in django3
```

You need to do this in order to access template files under `templates` folder in your main project directory.